# Best way to use switch case with mutiple params

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two conditional params in switch statement(TypeScript)

Please let me know what would be the best way to do below. Below is not code, I just tried to explain my issue.
I have 4 states(Nebraska, Alaska, Texas and Illinois) and  3 products (1,2,3). One state would have 1-3 products. I need to make a conditional statement based on a product in particular state

```
 switch(state){
    case 'Nebraska':{
    if(products === 1){
    // return someStatement1
    } else if(products === 2) {
    // return someStatement2
    } else {
      /// return case1Statement
    }
    } case 'Alaska' : {
    //// return case2Statement
    }
................
    }
```

Comment: What you did is totally fine. Alternatively, replace the `if` chain by a second (nested) `switch` statement.

Comment: If you are OK with 12 case instructions you could switch on a concatenation. But that feels like an XY problem. what is the problem you are trying to solve with swicth?

Answer (score 0):

You can defined an rule object and find statement in your rules as

```
var rule = [{ "state" : "AL", "product": "1", "statement": "s1"}, {"state" : "NY", "product": "2", "statement": "s2"}];

var statement = rule.find(c=>c.state == "AL" && c.product == "1").statement;

console.log(statement);
```

```js
var rule = [{ "state" : "AL", "product": "1", "statement": "s1"}, {"state" : "NY", "product": "2", "statement": "s2"}];

var statement = rule.find(c=>c.state == "AL" && c.product == "1").statement;

console.log(statement);
```